# Ceph RGW 16.2.7 CLI changes

Tags: ceph, ceph-rgw

I am trying to run a new Ceph cluster with Rados GW using the last software version 16.2.7, but when I set up RGW nodes I found out there are some changes in the CLI comparing with a version 16.2.4 I tested before.

The next commands are missed in the 16.2.7 version:

```
ceph dashboard set-rgw-api-user-id $USER
ceph dashboard set-rgw-api-access-key ...
ceph dashboard set-rgw-api-secret-key ...
```

they don't exist in `ceph dashboad -h` output on the 16.2.7 version:

```
# ceph dashboard -h | grep set-rgw-api | grep -v reset
dashboard set-rgw-api-access-key                     Set the RGW_API_ACCESS_KEY option value read from -i
dashboard set-rgw-api-admin-resource <value>         Set the RGW_API_ADMIN_RESOURCE option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-secret-key                     Set the RGW_API_SECRET_KEY option value read from -i
dashboard set-rgw-api-ssl-verify <value>             Set the RGW_API_SSL_VERIFY option value
```

But on the 16.2.4 version everything is on place:

```
# ceph dashboard -h | grep set-rgw-api | grep -v reset
dashboard set-rgw-api-access-key                                                                          Set the RGW_API_ACCESS_KEY option value read from -i <file>
dashboard set-rgw-api-admin-resource <value>                                                              Set the RGW_API_ADMIN_RESOURCE option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-host <value>                                                                        Set the RGW_API_HOST option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-port <value>                                                                        Set the RGW_API_PORT option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-scheme <value>                                                                      Set the RGW_API_SCHEME option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-secret-key                                                                          Set the RGW_API_SECRET_KEY option value read from -i <file>
dashboard set-rgw-api-ssl-verify <value>                                                                  Set the RGW_API_SSL_VERIFY option value
dashboard set-rgw-api-user-id <value>                                                                     Set the RGW_API_USER_ID option value
```

Do you know what is a replacement for this commands or where were they moved?
Thank you in advance.

UDP: In both cases the host OS is Debian 10.

The list of ceph packages is identical on both RGW setups:
16.2.4:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ceph
ii  ceph                              16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        distributed storage and file system                                                                                                
ii  ceph-base                         16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        common ceph daemon libraries and management tools                                                                                  
ii  ceph-common                       16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        common utilities to mount and interact with a ceph storage cluster                                                                 
ii  ceph-mgr                          16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        manager for the ceph distributed storage system                                                                                    
ii  ceph-mgr-modules-core             16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             all          ceph manager modules which are always enabled                                                                                      
ii  ceph-mon                          16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        monitor server for the ceph storage system                                                                                         
ii  ceph-osd                          16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        OSD server for the ceph storage system                                                                                             
ii  libcephfs2                        16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Ceph distributed file system client library                                                                                        
ii  libsqlite3-mod-ceph               16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        SQLite3 VFS for Ceph
ii  python3-ceph-argparse             16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             all          Python 3 utility libraries for Ceph CLI                                                                                            
ii  python3-ceph-common               16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             all          Python 3 utility libraries for Ceph                                                                                                
ii  python3-cephfs                    16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Python 3 libraries for the Ceph libcephfs library

# dpkg -l | grep rados
ii  librados2                         16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        RADOS distributed object store client library
ii  libradosstriper1                  16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        RADOS striping interface
ii  python3-rados                     16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Python 3 libraries for the Ceph librados library
ii  radosgw                           16.2.4-1~bpo10+1             amd64        REST gateway for RADOS distributed object store
```

16.2.7:

```
# dpkg -l | grep ceph
ii  ceph                              16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        distributed storage and file system
ii  ceph-base                         16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        common ceph daemon libraries and management tools
ii  ceph-common                       16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        common utilities to mount and interact with a ceph storage cluster
ii  ceph-mgr                          16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        manager for the ceph distributed storage system
ii  ceph-mgr-modules-core             16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             all          ceph manager modules which are always enabled
ii  ceph-mon                          16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        monitor server for the ceph storage system
ii  ceph-osd                          16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        OSD server for the ceph storage system
ii  libcephfs2                        16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Ceph distributed file system client library
ii  libsqlite3-mod-ceph               16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        SQLite3 VFS for Ceph
ii  python3-ceph-argparse             16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             all          Python 3 utility libraries for Ceph CLI
ii  python3-ceph-common               16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             all          Python 3 utility libraries for Ceph
ii  python3-cephfs                    16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Python 3 libraries for the Ceph libcephfs library

# dpkg -l | grep rados
ii  librados2                         16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        RADOS distributed object store client library
ii  libradosstriper1                  16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        RADOS striping interface
ii  python3-rados                     16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        Python 3 libraries for the Ceph librados library
ii  radosgw                           16.2.7-1~bpo10+1             amd64        REST gateway for RADOS distributed object store
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Ceph maillist:
Starting Pacific 16.2.6, cephadm now configures and manages the RGW
credentials. You can also trigger that auto-configuration on an upgraded
cluster with `ceph dashboard set-rgw-credentials`

[[docs]](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/mgr/dashboard/#enabling-the-object-gateway-management-frontend)